# Python read last line only but I want all even with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a funtion that takes a txt file filled with movies and ratings into dictionary
but the output it came out only read the last line of the same name
This is what I had so far

```
def read_ratings_data(f):
    input = {}
    for line in open(f):
        movie, rating, numId = line.split('|')
        input[movie] = rating
    print(input)
```

A sample from the txt file:

```
Toy Story (1995)|4.0|1
Toy Story (1995)|4.0|5
Toy Story (1995)|4.5|7
Toy Story (1995)|2.5|15
Toy Story (1995)|4.5|17
Toy Story (1995)|3.5|18
Jumanji (1995)|4.0|6
Jumanji (1995)|4.0|8
Jumanji (1995)|3.0|18
Jumanji (1995)|3.0|19
Jumanji (1995)|3.0|20
Jumanji (1995)|3.5|21
```

My output:

```
{'Toy Story (1995)': '3.5', 'Jumanji (1995)': '3.5'}
```

*Structure* of expected output:

```py
{"The Lion King (2019)" : [6.0, 7.5, 5.1], "Titanic (1997)": [7]}
```

It's suppose to store all the information including movies with same name.
It only took the last line of the same name

Comment: dictionaries can have only unique keys, also if you won't use `num_id` then replace it with `_`: `movie, rating, _ = line.split('|')`

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do with such a dictionary, how do you even expect to access any ratings in it? or do you want to get the average rating?

Comment: the output I'm expecting is for example "The Lion King (2019)" : [6.0, 7.5, 5.1], "Titanic (1997)": [7] that will sort all the movies with the same title but all ratings but I didn't get to that part yet

Comment: good to know now, next time please include the expected output in the question please

Comment: also the unique key name doesn't seems do the trick

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I misinterpreted your comment, yes of course, sample input and output should have the same data but in this case it doesn't matter really that much, the structure of output matters and how the data is provided

Comment: @Matiiss Btw I think they shouldn't just do it "next time" but also still this time. Next time they should just do it right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments I understand that you want the movie name as a key in the dictionary to represent a list of the movie's ratings in the text file:

```py
def read_ratings_data(f):
    movies = dict()
    # use a context manager so that it takes care
    # of exceptions and automatically closes the file
    with open(f) as file:
        for line in file:
            movie, rating, _ = line.strip().split('|')
            # if the dictionary already has the movie
            # it also means it has a corresponding list 
            # so just append to that list the rating
            if movie in movies.keys():
                movies[movie].append(rating)
            else:
                # if there is not yet a key
                # with the movie name
                # create a new key and as
                # the value use a list that contains
                # the rating
                movies[movie] = [rating]
    return movies


print(read_ratings_data('text.txt'))
```

`'text.txt'` would be the file where you have the data

Answer (score -1):

Based on the expected output you've provided in the comments, you need to initialize the dictionary with a list and then append each rating considering the `movie` as the key. 
You code was not appending the current value but it was replacing it every time the same movie was read.

```
def read_ratings_data(f):
    movieData = {}
    for line in open(f):
        movie, rating, numId = line.split('|')
        if movieData.get(movie):
            movieData[movie].append(rating)
        else:
            movieData[movie] = [rating]
    print(movieData )
```

**Output**

```
{'Toy Story (1995)': ['4.0', '4.0', '4.5', '2.5', '4.5', '3.5'], 'Jumanji (1995)': ['4.0', '4.0', '3.0', '3.0', '3.0', '3.5']}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try this after cleaning your keys, because dicts have only a unique key type:

```py
def read_ratings_data(f):
    input_ = {}
    for line in open(f,'r'):
        movie, rating, numId = line.split('|')
        input_.update({movie:rating})
    print(input_)
```

Other suggestion given in comments is to iterate by `with open(f,'r') as file:` and then perform your iteration step line by line. You dont need to use `f.close()`, because the `with` statement makes the file `f` to live only inside himself.

maybe you need this:

```
import pandas as pd
col_names = ['movie','rating','numId']
s = pd.read_csv(f,names=col_names,sep='|')[['movie','rating']].to_records() 
# you can change .to_record() with .to_dict()
print(s)
```

output:

```
[( 0, 'Toy Story (1995)', 4. ) ( 1, 'Toy Story (1995)', 4. )
 ( 2, 'Toy Story (1995)', 4.5) ( 3, 'Toy Story (1995)', 2.5)
 ( 4, 'Toy Story (1995)', 4.5) ( 5, 'Toy Story (1995)', 3.5)
 ( 6, 'Jumanji (1995)', 4. ) ( 7, 'Jumanji (1995)', 4. )
 ( 8, 'Jumanji (1995)', 3. ) ( 9, 'Jumanji (1995)', 3. )
 (10, 'Jumanji (1995)', 3. ) (11, 'Jumanji (1995)', 3.5)]
```